# How do I track changes to the Redux store after each dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a TTRPG character generation tool, and decided that one thing I'd like to add - for readability - is a tracker that updates when and how your character's stats, abilities, skills, etc change.

This is, however, after I'd already finished writing the code for the majority of the tool, and I was hoping not to rewrite every component that modifies the character's stats, skills, etc (read: all of them.)

What I'm hoping for is either a tool that can naturally track single changes to the store (Without having to store (and compare to) the past state in its entirety) Or a middleware that lets me dispatch an action that can contain just the changes from the most recent character updates.

Comment: You could probably just add some middleware of your own into each reducer logic, that is the logger. So its all contained with in the reducer code

Comment: @ColinHale I could - and will, if no one gives me a better option - but the number of reducers I'd have to modify makes it worth it to at least check beforehand